# How to Receive Data from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to learn/know how to get or receive data inputted through my `prompt`? For example, I wanted to receive data from my restaurant menu from customers. How would I be able to do that, if possible, in javascript?

Comment: [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) documentation has all the info you need to use `prompt`

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
const result = prompt("What is your name?");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The prompt box/function resembles the input function in Python; the function returns the entry user, well, entered. So you should declare the function as a variable:

```
var username = prompt("Username?");
```

and the *username* equals what the user has entered.

A note: username would be equal to *null* if the user refuses to enter anything and would be equal to *""* if the user just clicks on "OK".

You can also have a default value for the prompt like this:

```
var username = prompt("Username?", "@Example")
```